# Solve recurrence

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relation

![enter image description here][1]

I have a problem to solve this recurrence. I tried by myself but it doesn't look understandable. Solve the following recurrence

Comment: Can you typeset your recurrence function in LaTeX? I don't realy understand what you mean right now.

Comment: You are right. With the current formatting the recurrence isn't understandable. From what I can extract, it looks like a straightforward induction on n should do the trick.

Comment: What about matching opening braces with closing ones ?  What does "*" mean here? This is unreadable. Why is the math in the title different from taht in the body of the question. I call it math,  because I do not dare call it an equation.

Comment: sorry guys there you have a picture now please help

Comment: A picture is not acceptable. Please use MathJax formatting, like Aryabhata did on your other question. Also, what did you try? What theorems have you studied in class, that you could use in your solution?

Comment: This is a dump of an exercise problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See also [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/470/) for our homework policy, and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594) for a relevant discussion. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/). If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As FrankW mentioned, your question seems to be: Solve the recurrence

> $$f(n+1) = \begin{cases}2 & n=0\\f(n)+3 & n>0\end{cases}$$

The solution $f(n) = 3n-1$ is already given. It just needs to proven:

- base case: $f(1)=3-1=2$
- otherwise: $f(n+1) = 3(n+1) - 1 = 3n + 3 - 1 = 3n - 1 + 3 = f(n) + 3$

**Edit**

As to your comment on how to find $f(n) = 3n-1$ (though it was given in the question), use induction on n:

- $f(1) = 2$
- $f(2) = 2+3 = 5$
- $f(3) = 5+3 = 8$
- $f(4) = 8+3 = 11$
- $f(5) = 11+3 = 14$
- $f(6) = 14+3 = 17$

So try to find a function for which $f(1) = 2, f(2) = 5, f(3) = 8, f(4) = 11, f(5) = 14, f(6) = 17,\ \dots$ Clearly it is $f(n) = 3n-1$

Comment: it is prove the recurrence solution as you saw inn picture  i dont understabnd did you get f(n)=3n−1. and is this all for prove

Comment: It's all there is to prove. The base case and the recurrence function. I didn't find the f(n)=3n-1, it was given in the question.

Comment: ok thank you very much i have starting now with recurrence and it looks complicated

Comment: I edited my post to show you how f(n)=3n-1 can be found when it's not given

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594).

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the image, I think  the exercise is trying to ask the following:

> Given the recurrence $$f(n) = \begin{cases}2 & n=1\\f(n-1)+3 & n>1\end{cases},$$
>   show that $f(n) = 3n-1$.

Does this help?